# Convert .ply to .png (.jpeg) with Python

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, png

did you know how to convert point clouds file to an image format using python?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of this? https://github.com/phistrom/mesh2img This should be able to convert the polygons to PNG

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/) supports this; from the [docs](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/) (I don't have it installed myself) It looks like you could do:

```
img=open3d.io.read_point_cloud("filename.ply")
open3d.io.write_image("filename.png",img)
```

It [supports](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/file_io.html) both ply as input and png as output.